# How to fork a process in windows bash from normal command window?

Tags: windows, bash, shell

I installed `ubuntu bash` on windows 10 and tried to fork a process from it. It works fine if I fork the process inside the `bash` but it doesn't work if I run `bash` command from windows normal command window. Below is the error I got:

```
>bash -c "mlaunch init --single"
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 635
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100

can't start process, return code 100. tried to launch: mongod  --dbpath /mnt/c/Users/devel/joey/data/db --logpath /mnt/c/Users/devel/joey/data/mongod.log --port 27017 --logappend --fork
```

it seems that I couldn't fork a process by typing `bash -c "xxxx"` command. It works if I type `bash` first to switch to bash shell then run the above command. But I really need to run it from normal window command. How can I achieve that?

Comment: It looks to me like the fork succeeded, but the child process was unable to launch `mongod`, presumably because of the problem with the path you've already asked about?

Comment: The mongod can be found actually. It works when I type `bash` first then run `mlaunch init --single`.

Comment: Finally found the problem. You are right that `mongod` failed to start. The reason is because of the file path. It will fail if I use any path from `/mnt/c/xxx`. It works fine after changing the path. Not sure what special about `/mnt/c/` directory

Comment: It has Windows file system semantics rather than Linux file system semantics.  Some applications aren't going to like that.